# How to ignore a property after mappings have been defined?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm aware of how to ignore a property at mapping definition time. However, I'm trying to add a common logic to all mapings, to ignore properties based on some conditions. For this, I'm using a code like this.

```
public static void ProcessMappings(this IMappingEngine engine)
{
    var typeMaps = engine.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps();
    foreach (var typeMap in typeMaps)
    {
        if (typeof(MyClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeMap.DestinationType)) 
        {
            // here let's say I want to ignore property "Property"
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, given an instance of `TypeMap`, how can I set a property to be ignored?

Comment: I'd say, that you create a [`Attribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653979.aspx) for your class. And assign attributes to your properties. Then work with it inside your `ProcessMappings` Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var propInfo = typeMap.DestinationType.GetProperty("PropertyToIgnore");
if (propInfo != null)
{
    typeMap.FindOrCreatePropertyMapFor(new  AutoMapper.Impl.PropertyAccessor(propInfo)).Ignore();
}
```

Ignore method is used to ignore the properties/members

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I got to a similar solution too.

Comment: I am trying to implement something like this, but automapper seems to not have the PropertyAccessor-Class anymore.. any suggestions?